# find neighbours at distance d in matrix + matlab

Tags: matlab

I want all neighbors of a point coordinate in a matrix at a distance d from it along with that point.

What is the most efficient way to generate such a sub-matrix ?

For example if `A = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ; 4 , 5 , 6 ; 7 ,8 ,9]`

then for `d = 0 and data 5` i would get the answer as `5` but for `d = 1` i will get the matrix A as the result since the size of A itself is 3X3.

At the same time if the index does not exist in the matrix then i should get 0 at that point.

so for `data point 2 and d = 1` the answer would be `[ 0 , 0 , 0 ; 1 , 2 ,3 ; 4 , 5 , 6]`

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out ...

```
A = padarray( A , [d d] )
% assuming the data is at r row and c col do the following

A( r : r + 2d , c : c + 2 d )
```

I hope it works ... did'nt really check !!

Comment: octave does not know padarray :-( but nice if it works so compact

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.  I'll leave you to turn it into a function.  Let `n` denote the value at the centre of your sub-array, which is `5` in your example.

```
z = zeros(size(A,1)+2*d,size(A,2)+2*d);
z(d+1:d+size(A,1),d+1:d+size(A,2)) = A;
[r,c] = find(z==n);
z(r-d:r+d,c-d:c+d)
```

**EDIT**

Try this version, which is as inadequately tested as my earlier attempt.  This still won't cope if the find expression returns multiple locations.

And I still make no warranties as to the efficiency of this.

Comment: case n=2,d=1, (=> r=1) gives r-d=0 => zero subindex

Comment: It is incorrect... i can assume that i know r,c but it is still giving me wrong answer in terms of neighbours

Comment: I took the following matrix 'A = [ 1 , 2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12;13,14,15,16]' and gave r = 2 and c=2 with d = 1 ... it returns me ' 0     0     0 ;     0     1     2 ;
     0     5     6'

Comment: So, now over to you to fix either my offering or @Kyss's.

Answer (score 0):

To start with the case that you are inside A, instead of giving `d=0` and `data_point=5` you should give `data_point=[2,2]`. If you have it given as `5` you can convert by

```
ij = [ceil(data_point/size(A,1)), rem(data_point-1, size(A,1))+1]
```

or use find, as in High's answer, depending how to interpret your question.

The following function

```
function B = find_neigh(A,ij,d)
imin = max(ij(1)-d,1);
imax = min(ij(1)+d,size(A,1));
jmin = max(ij(2)-d,1);
jmax = min(ij(2)+d,size(A,2));
B = zeros(2*d+1,2*d+1);
r1 = max(2-ij(1)+d,1);
c1 = max(2-ij(2)+d,1);
B(r1:r1+imax-imin, c1:c1+jmax-jmin) = A(imin:imax,jmin:jmax);
```

should return you the desired result. Call it for example with

```
A = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9];
find_neigh(A,[1,2],1)
```

Edit: fixed two, no three bugs, and made it a function

Comment: you mean with regards to my fixes, or did you find one more mistake?

Comment: No @Kyss, wrt your original post, I've not tested your code at all.  Crikey, I've hardly tested mine.

Comment: Could you give a working example ? I can have it as data[2][2] ie i know where the data point is.... The answer given by @ High Performance Mark unfortunately did'nt work....

Comment: ok, I put the code into a function now and gave an example how to call it. Save the function as find_neigh.m. Have fun!